# Filter by drop down and text box Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects with a boolean property.  I need a three-stage drop down which will show all, show active (those with `true` as property name) and show trash (those with `false` as property name).  On the initial page load the default view needs to be only those with `true`, and if the user selects show all, then it shows true and false values, if show trash, then it shows only the false values.  What I have currently will load with only the true values being shown, but when I change the value from the drop down, all the values in the drop down are removed.
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6dvn1aanGSxe15BH46zT)

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);



app.controller('FilterController',function($scope){
    $scope.data = [{
        name: 'darrin',
        markedForDelete:true
    },{
        name: 'megan',
        markedForDelete: true

    },{
        name: 'kim',
        markedForDelete:false
    },{
        name: 'winky',
        markedForDelete: false
    }];

    //show all should show both true and false
    //show active should only show true
    //show trash should only show false
    $scope.filterOptions = [{
        name: 'Show all'

    },{
        name: 'Show active'
    },{
        name: 'Show trash'
    }];
    $scope.customFilter = function(data){
        if(data.markedForDelete){
            return true;
        }
        if(!data.markedForDelete){
            return false;
        }
    }
    $scope.name = "Darrin";
})
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="FilterController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
    <select ng-model="filterOptions" ng-options="f.name for f in filterOptions"></select>
    <div ng-repeat="d in data | filter:customFilter ">{{d.name}}</div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What's the best way to go about something like this, and why is it that when I make a change to the drop down its values are being deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong.  First, you need somewhere to store the selected filter option.

```
//Default to first option.
$scope.selectedFilterOption = $scope.filterOptions[0];
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="selectedFilterOption" ng-options="f.name for f in filterOptions"></select>
```

The next problem is that your custom filter doesn't take into account the selected filter.  Change it to something like this:

```
$scope.customFilter = function(data) {
    if ($scope.selectedFilterOption.name == 'Show all')
      return true;
    else if ($scope.selectedFilterOption.name == 'Show active' && data.markedForDelete == false)
      return true;
    else if ($scope.selectedFilterOption.name == 'Show trash' && data.markedForDelete == true)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OpmiGZUWjb0VL2WdUsiu?p=preview)

Comment: Great, thanks.  Do you know why the behavior that I had was causing the text in the drop down to dissappear?

Comment: Why does this work without adding a $watch to the filterOptions?

Comment: It was disappearing because you had assigned the ng-model on the dropdown to be `filterOptions`, which is the same variable that holds the options themselves.  Once, you selected an item, your list was overwritten with the selected item.

Comment: You don't need a $watch on `filterOptions` because the options themselves don't change.  There is a $watch on `selectedFilterOption`, but Angular adds it behind the scenes so you don't have to handle it.